# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I tested this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        // Image
        Image image = new Image("za.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        // Text
        Text t = new Text();
        t.setText("Do you want to quit?");

        // Buttons
        Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");
        Button btnNo = new Button("No");
        btnYes.setStyle("-fx-background-color:\n"
                + "        #090a0c,\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#38424b 0%, #1f2429 20%, #191d22 100%),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#20262b, #191d22),\n"
                + "        radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(114,131,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: 5,4,3,5;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,0;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: white;\n"
                + "    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );\n"
                + "    -fx-font-family: \"Arial\";\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(white, #d0d0d0);\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 12px;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;");

        btnNo.setStyle("-fx-background-color:\n"
                + "        #090a0c,\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#38424b 0%, #1f2429 20%, #191d22 100%),\n"
                + "        linear-gradient(#20262b, #191d22),\n"
                + "        radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(114,131,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: 5,4,3,5;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,0;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: white;\n"
                + "    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );\n"
                + "    -fx-font-family: \"Arial\";\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(white, #d0d0d0);\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 12px;\n"
                + "    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;");

        // Buttons layout
        HBox hbox = new HBox(8); // spacing = 8
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 15; -fx-font-size: 15pt;");
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnYes, btnNo);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ffffff,#f3f3f4);\n"
                + "    -fx-border-width: 1 1 1 1;\n"
                + "    -fx-border-color: #b4b4b4 transparent #b4b4b4 transparent;\n"
                + "    -fx-font-size: 1.083333em;\n"
                + "    -fx-text-fill: #292929;");

        bp.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20));
        //Button btnTop = new Button("Top");
        bp.setTop(null);
        //Button btnLeft = new Button("Left");
        bp.setLeft(imageView);
        //Button btnCenter = new Button("Center");
        bp.setCenter(t);
        //Button btnRight = new Button("Right");
        bp.setRight(null);
        //Button btnBottom = new Button("Bottom");
        bp.setBottom(hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Executing com.javafx.main.Main from /home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/DX-57DC/dist/run429319394/DX-57DC.jar using platform /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:986)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:538)
    at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC.start(DX57DC.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:979)
    ... 12 more
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory /home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/DX-57DC/dist/run429319394
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I placed the image file next to the java source code file but the file is not found. Can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do

```
javafx.scene.image.Image image = new javafx.scene.image.Image(getClass().getResource("za.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
```

Or simply

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("za.jpg").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 45):

```
Image image = new Image("za.png");
```

The constructor of this needs to point to a URI, so if you're pointing to something on the file system it'd be:

```
Image image = new Image("file:za.png");
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
Image image = new Image(new File("za.png").toURI().toString());
```

...which is arguably neater. If the image is bundled in your jar rather than on the filesystem, you can obtain the URI like so:

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("za.jpg").toURI().toString());
```

Most methods / constructors in JavaFX that take a string as a parameter in this way (i.e. specifying a resource) do so via string URI's rather than just a plain file path or URL.

Comment: Are you sure? I get `no suitable constructor found for Image(URI)`

Comment: Sorry, should have been a toString() on there. Edited now.

Comment: This solution worked for me whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: @skrilmps wondering why you see any difference between the accepted answer and this: as long as the resource is in the same package (or folder, if going the file protocol) as the calling code they should have the exact same effect. Both file protocol and loading via class.getResource support relative input paths.  Which are implicitely converted to absolute paths for the  sake of Image (which is implemented to load via classLoader) in both answers.