# Cannot build a JavaFX Maven project

Tags: java, maven, java-8, openjfx

I have installed `openjdk-8` and `openjfx`, but I still cannot build any Maven project containing JavaFX elements. The Netbeans linting doesn't show any error, but when I click on "Build Project" the output shows:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project javafx: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT: Attaching pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>javafx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

EDIT2: Debug output says:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ javafx ---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

and nbactions.xml: https://pastebin.com/0rGDD1Wh

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077870/maven-wont-run-my-project-failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven If it doesn't help you, please share you pom file

Comment: I have already read this question, but it didn't help me. I attached my pom file, but it's quite simple.

Comment: please do what the build output says - Run with debug output enabled (and attach to the issue). Also interesting is the initial output printed by netbeans that shows what's being put on the cmd line. And possibly the content of nbactions.xml file.

Comment: Ran with debug output, attached it and also nbactions.xml

Comment: from nbactions.xml file is the root of the problem. One cannot have both -jar <jar> and -classpath <cp> <mainClass> at the same time.

Comment: I can see jar only in the <packaging>. How to solve the problem?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: the problem on some mixed-release version of Debian and the problem can be openjfx of Java 8 and libopenjfx-jni of Java 11, check that you have proper version of libopenjfx-jni, it should have libglass.so, which seems to be unavailable on problematic machine.

Comment: My terminal says `libopenjfx-jni is already the newest version (11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2)`. But I can't find libglass.so. Where to download it and how to install it?

Comment: you should downgrade your libopenjfx-jni to match with your openjdk version (8). You can use https://pkgs.org/download/libopenjfx-jni to download the correct version. You can also try using openjdk 11 if it is applicable for you

Comment: Okay, I tried installing libopenjfx-jni-8 from the link, but the output still says `Failed to execute goal...` I could try upgrading openjdk to version 11, will it work with openjfx?

Comment: I installed openjdk-11, which is defaultly installed by `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`. Does Netbeans 8.2 support openjdk-11?

Comment: looks like it doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246826/cant-create-project-on-netbeans-8-2-with-jdk-10 . My suggestion is to try downgrade libopenjfx-jni to the one compatible with JDK8

Comment: Now I have openjdk version 8 and libopenjfx-jni version 8. I'm able to build the project, but not run it. The error output is still the same: Failed to execute...

Comment: Ok we are getting there. How do you run the project? With maven? And, what is the stack trace now?

Comment: I'm running the project in Netbeans - either Run Project or Run File. The full output is here: https://pastebin.com/mqTYCvxP

Comment: looks like a functional error - something in your Application. not related to the openjdk or JavaFX

Comment: No javafx application works in my computer currently. The applications work on another machines.

Comment: Got it. According to the above stacktrace you shared, the error now is something with your App. Try to look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990482/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-url-or-resource-not-found

Comment: My app is quite simple and works on other machines https://pastebin.com/Zycbbx7L

Comment: according the stack trace and the app you provided, there is no file named "hero.png" in your root classpath. try to change the path for the file

Comment: The file is in either src/main/resources or in root folder. If I remove the lines with the file, the program still won't run.